# How to forbid transfering URL like devtools:// from chrome browser to Google search (windows)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I type URL like

```
 devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:4000
```

in Linux, Chrome understand this URL and handle it, but if I type this URL on my Windows computer, Chrome understand this string as searching string only. How to force Chrome to understand that is URL, not a string for searching on Google engine?

Comment: Must be one of Chrome's safe-guards in Windows e.g. it ignores chrome:// URLs from external programs. You can use Autohotkey `send {F6}devtools://...{Enter}` or do the same from python, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @wOxxOm I know how to call Devtools by mouse and hotkey, but currently I want to force Chrome working with his normal standard URL instead  of ignore it and sending URL to Google search engine. Some setting maybe prevent processing URL starting from devtools://

Comment: @wOxxOm, yes, you are right, this is a some way to avoid something setting of windows  or Google chrome. I have created VBS script with lines sendkey "{F6}", than sendkeys "devtools://..." and Chrome understand this URL as needed (currently I need to use socket inspector from Google DevTools). It is a solution, one kind of solution.